# Google Cloud Speech Versions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

Google Cloud Speech API has few versions. If I need develop an app using Cloud Speech what version should I need to use?

```
1.com.google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.
2.com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.*
3.com.google.cloud.speech.v1
```

What are the differences between each version?

Answer (score 2):

According to Google Speech API release notes, v1beta1 is deprecated as of April 2017.

https://cloud.google.com/speech/release-notes

You should use `com.google.cloud.speech.v1`

Generally speaking, beta versions work for testing new features that are not available yet, but they are dynamic and some features may change before the final version. They are not recommended for production code.